# fadeOut() and fadeIn() mystery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem: some elements inside the array `slides` are hiding or `.show`(ing) instead of fading out\in. You can see it in action at http://www.bonus-click.com - just press on an item in the lower menu at the header. See the image on the mobile? It's not fading like all the other elements in the array (the background, the text at the bottom. Any idea why?

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lnqcanf9/

**JavaScript:**

```
 function menu(slidernum) {
    clearInterval(autoSlider);
    $(fadeOutDivs).fadeOut( 300 ).promise().done(function() {
        $(slides[slidernum]).fadeIn( 300 );
    });
    resetColor(this);
};
```

Comment: If it was in a jsfiddle, I'd try to debug it, but as is it's hard.

Comment: A demo would help (jsbin, codepen), and/or screenshots.

Comment: There is really not enough information to determine. Some things that might help: What is resetColor() doing? What is the selector for fadeOutDivs?

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnqcanf9/